Numpy array `fill_value` fills matrix with same object, with same id, not independent objects
Here is a short example which demonstrates how numpy array creation works with fill_value:
class ExampleObject():
    pass

my_array = numpy.full(
    shape=(3, 3),
    fill_value=ExampleObject(),
)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print(id(my_array[i][j]) # returns same id for all entries

It is obvious why this is happening. fill_value is set to a single instance of an object. In this case ExampleObject().
The behaviour I actually want is for each entry to be independent, such that each entry in the matrix is a unique instance of ExampleObject.
I also tried this:
my_array = numpy.fill(
    shape=(3, 3),
    fill_value=[ExampleObject() for _ in range(3*3)],
)

however, this failed with error ValueError: could not broadcast input arry from shape (9,) into shape (3,3)
Is there a way to make this work? Possibly something like using a function (or other callable) which can return a new ExampleObject each time it is called? (Basically a factory function.)

How about my_array = np.asarray([ExampleObject() for _ in range(3 * 3)]).reshape(3, 3)? Not very elegant, but effective.

@simon Sure, seems like an ok solution. My alternative idea was to do [[ExampleObject() for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)] but I prefer your idea to this

But why? Numpy is for numerical arrays. Numpy arrays with object data types are slow.

@jared You're correct. In this context I am using it to get the behaviour of matrix math operations, but with differently behaved elements.

The only way to get separate instances is to call the creator for each.  That's basic python.  In previous SO I've suggested vectorize or frompyfunc as tools for iterating over object arrays.  It's not significantly faster than list comprehension, but broadcasting is cleaner.

Looking at the available NumPy array creation routines, there is no particular candidate for the given problem, it seems. So a for loop might be necessary, in the end.
One could start from a list, for example:
my_array = np.asarray([ExampleObject() for _ in range(3 * 3)]).reshape(3, 3)

Or one could directly use an iterator:
my_array = np.fromiter((ExampleObject() for _ in range(3 * 3)), dtype=object).reshape(3, 3)

What might look promising but isn't particular useful when looking closer is fromfunction(): It doesn't work with functions producing scalars (single array elements) but assumes that the given function takes care of broadcasting the result into the correct shape. So while one could probably also make fromfunction() work, it would for sure be more effort than the previous two approaches.
